# deleteing multiple files in remote box via sh

Tags: unix

- Requirement

Several files in remote machines ought to be deleted via sh. Name of the files to be deleted are know

- Approach

1) script was written with ftp (requires credential) and delete command. File names were passed as array(iterated via for loop-with ftp+delete commands enclosed within for loop). files were not getting deleted by this approach

2) another approach attempted was to pass temp.ftp(which contains delete command) to ftp command and rm the temp.ftp file eg.ftp <

- Request

require pointers to delete muliple files in remote machine via shell script

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using ssh instead of ftp for interfacing with the remote unix machine. 
SSH allows you to run remote commands easily and securely.

Read [this article](http://bashcurescancer.com/run_remote_commands_with_ssh.html) for more info.